# EF code first does not return related relationship for entity

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using Code First and Repository pattern

Entity:

```
   public class Company : BaseEntity
    {
        private ICollection<CompanyRole> _companyRoles;

        private ICollection<Branch> _branches;

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int CityId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CompanyRole> CompanyRoles
        {
            get { return _companyRoles ?? (_companyRoles = new List<CompanyRole>()); }
            protected set { _companyRoles = value; }
        }

        public virtual ICollection<Branch> Branches
        {
            get { return _branches ?? (_branches = new List<Branch>()); }
            protected set { _branches = value; }
        }

        public virtual City City { get; set; }
    }
```

FluentApi mapping:

```
    public class CompanyConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Company>
    {
        public CompanyConfiguration()
        {
            this.ToTable("Company");
            this.HasKey(c => c.Id);
            this.Property(c => c.Name).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();

            this.HasRequired(c => c.City)
             .WithMany()
             .HasForeignKey(c => c.CityId)
             .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);      

            this.HasMany(v => v.CompanyRoles)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("Company_CompanyRole_Mapping")); 
        }
    }

    public class BranchConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Branch>
    {
        public BranchConfiguration()
        {
            this.ToTable("Branch");
            this.HasKey(c => c.Id);
            this.Property(c => c.Name).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
            this.HasRequired(c => c.Company)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.CompanyId);
        }
    }
```

Repository:

```
    public class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        public EFRepository(DbContext dbContext)
        {
            if (dbContext == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("dbContext");
            DbContext = dbContext;
            DbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
        }

        protected DbContext DbContext { get; set; }

        protected DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }

        public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return DbSet;
        }

        public virtual T GetById(int id)
        {
            return DbSet.Find(id);
        }

    }
```

When I use the method GetById it returns me Company but CompanyRoles, Branches and City is null(but CityId has value). Expected that GetById method will return entity with related relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use similar pattern in my projects. When I create repository and I need to extend any method of generic repository I prefer:

```
    public class CompanyRepository : EFRepository<Company>, ICompanyRepository
```

And then implement method `GetCompany`

```
  public Company GetCompany(int id)
    {
        return this.DbContext.Set<Company>()
           .Include(a => a.CompanyRoles)
           .Include(a => a.Branches)
           .SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);}
```

Other method is to load collections manually after receving entity:

```
public Company GetCompany(int id)
    {
        var company =  this.GetById(id);
        this.DbContext.Entry(company).Collection(a => a.CompanyRoles).Load();
        this.DbContext.Entry(company).Collection(a => a.Branches).Load();
        return company;
}
```